# NextJs 13 throws an error when I use "Email" word in span

Tags: next.js13

I get a very weird error.

Here is my authForm component:

```
'use client'

import React, {FormEvent, useState} from 'react';
import "./AuthForm.scss"
import {createClientComponentClient} from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import {useRouter} from "next/navigation";

type OnSubmitCredentials = {
    email:string,
    password:string,
    passwordConfirmation?: string
    }


type AuthFormProps = {
    type: "signIn" | "signUp",
}

const AuthForm = ({type}:AuthFormProps) => {
//states
    const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
        email: "",
        password: "",
        passwordConfirmation: ""
    })
    const [error, setError] = useState<string>("")
    const [pending, setPending] = useState(false)
//routing
    const router = useRouter()



//functions
    const onSubmit = async (e:FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        //here should be some input checks. (passwords are correct etc.)
        setPending(true)
        const supabase = createClientComponentClient()
        if (type==="signIn"){
            //signing in

        }else {
            //signing up
            const {error}=await supabase.auth.signUp({
                email: credentials.email,
                password: credentials.password,
                options:{
                    emailRedirectTo: `${location.origin}/api/auth/callback`
                }
            })
            if (error){
                setError(error.message)
            }else{
                setPending(false)
                router.push(`/verify`)
            }
        }
        setPending(false)

    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="auth-form">
            <label className="auth-form__label">
                <span className="auth-form__title">Email</span>
                <input
                    className="auth-form__input"
                    value={credentials.email}
                    onChange={(e)=>setCredentials(prev=>({...prev, email:e.target.value}))}
                    type="email"
                />
            </label>
            <label className="auth-form__label">
                <span className="auth-form__title">Password:</span>
                <input
                    className="auth-form__input"
                    value={credentials.password}
                    onChange={(e)=>setCredentials(prev=>({...prev, password:e.target.value}))}
                    type="password"
                />
            </label>
            {type ==="signUp" &&
                <label className="auth-form__label">
                    <span className="auth-form__title">Password confirmation:</span>
                    <input
                        className="auth-form__input"
                        value={credentials.passwordConfirmation}
                        onChange={(e)=>setCredentials(prev=>({...prev, passwordConfirmation:e.target.value}))}
                        type="password"
                    />
                </label>
            }
            {!!error && <span className="error-box">{error}</span>}
            {!pending && <button className="btn auth-form__btn">{type === "signUp" ? "Sign up" : "Sign in"}</button>}
            {pending && <button disabled className="btn auth-form__btn">{type === "signUp" ? "Signing up..." : "Signing in..."}</button>}
        </form>
    );
};

export default AuthForm;
```

nextJs Throws an error: **Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a `<div>` in `<label>`.**

When I change the word "Email" that is located in first label, the error disappears. When I use the word "email" in a different form i have on my website, i also get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

What hapens if you change it to
`<span className="auth-form__title">{"Email"}</span>`

Comment: nothing changes, get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Replace the label tag and instead use a div tag, this is a semantic HTML error you are getting.

```
  <div className="auth-form__label">
                <span className="auth-form__title">Email</span>
                <input
                    className="auth-form__input"
                    value={credentials.email}
                    onChange={(e)=>setCredentials(prev=>({...prev, email:e.target.value}))}
                    type="email"
                />
            </div>
```

Comment: then I get an error: Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <label>.. nextJs thinks that the span element is a div element /:

Comment: If you put ":" after Email does it still give error?   <span className="auth-form__title">Email:</span>